# How to Setup RDP on AWS EC2 Instance and access it from Windows

Tags: rhel, aws, xrdp, tightvnc

I have been trying to get GUI of Linux machines installed on AWS CLoud, for that I have tried installing VNC Server and RDP too, both did not work, after the setup in both the cases - I am able to login to the machine, however, it does not show up. It's a blank screen.

For now, let me explain what I did to configure RDP on this machine.

https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-xrdp-remote-desktop-to-centos-6-rhel-6.html

Where I did the below:

1. `rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`
2. `yum -y install xrdp tigervnc-server`
3. `service xrdp start`

Now I can connect to EC2 instance using RDP from windows using the public IP, however, there is nothing, only a blank screen shows up.

How to get the real desktop of EC2 instance (RHEL 6.5)?

Comment: What fails? Edit your question and show the steps and their output.

Comment: Edited. There is no error as such, I just can't see any icons on the desktop and also not able to do anything.

Comment: Unless you tell us how you set it up we can't advise you on which step(s) you have missed out.

Comment: I have edited  the question, I did not do anything else apart from this, and these steps works fine on local machine, however, does not work on AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: When you say "_blank screen_" do you mean a black screen, a [grey cross-hatched screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303786/trouble-getting-tightvnc-to-display-screen), or something else? Is there a mouse pointer (and does it move when you move your mouse)?

Comment: There is nothing on the screen, can't even see the mouse pointer moving, but it logs in properly without any problem. No idea, what is missing here.